# The type ArrayGSackIterable<T> must implement the inherited abstract method GSackIterableADT<T>.remove()

Tags: java, eclipse, iterator, iterable

This is an example run in our Java class today with no problem but when I added the files into a new project I am having the following error. Can you please tell me if I have added files wrongly or maybe the professor was using an slightly different version of the files? Can you let me know what's the reason for this error and how to fix it?

[image]

The code for each of the file is as following: ArrayGSackIterable.java:
    import java.util.Iterator;

```
public class ArrayGSackIterable<T> extends ArrayGSack<T> implements GSackIterableADT<T> {

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new ArrayGSackIterator<T>(items, numItems);
    }

}
```

and for ArrayGSackIterator.java:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class ArrayGSackIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

    private E[] items;
    private int numItems, curr;

    public ArrayGSackIterator(E[] gsackitems, int num) {
        items = gsackitems;
        numItems = num;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return curr < numItems;
    }

    public E next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return items[curr++];
    }

    public void remove() {

    }

}
```

and finally for GSackIterableADT.java:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public interface GSackIterableADT<T> extends Iterable<T> {
        void add(T item);
        T remove() throws NoSuchElementException;
        boolean isEmpty();
        Iterator<T> iterator();
}
```

UPDATE: Apparently I had to add these two files from another .zip file. GSackADT.java:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public interface GSackADT<T> {
    void add(T item);
    T remove() throws NoSuchElementException;
    boolean isEmpty();
}
```

ArrayGSack.java:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ArrayGSack<T> implements GSackADT<T> {

    // Internal storage and accounting members
    protected T[] items;
    protected int numItems;
    private static final int INIT_SIZE = 100;

    public ArrayGSack() {
        items = (T[]) new Object[INIT_SIZE];
        numItems = 0;
    }

    public void add(T item) {
        if (numItems == items.length) expandStorage();
        items[numItems++] = item;
    }

    public T remove() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (numItems < 1) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return items[numItems--];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return numItems == 0;
    }

    // Internal method to handle capacity issues
    private void expandStorage() {
        T[] oldItems = items;
        items = (T[]) new Object[2 * items.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < oldItems.length; i++) 
            items[i] = oldItems[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: your class `ArrayGSackIterable` implements `GSackIterableADT` but doesn't provide implementation for all abstract methods

Comment: What is `ArratGSack`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is complaining for an unimplemented method `remove` from interface `GSackIterableADT`. 
Your professor might have done either of these to make it run:

- Deleted `remove` method from `GSackIterableADT` interface
- Marked `ArrayGSackIterable` as an abstract class

Comment: I commented all the code related to the remove, but yet I am receiving error. Regarding the second approach, I am not sure how to do it. Can you please be more elaborative with some possible piece of code?

Comment: @MonaJalal For the second approach, simply add abstract in your class definition: public abstract class ArrayGSackIterable . But if you mark class abstract you wouldn't be able to instantiate it. Then it will be meant to be extended and used.

Comment: well it didn't help. It says ArrayGSack cannot be resolved to a type!

Comment: @MonaJalal that seems to be the reason of your trouble, u need to have ArrayGSack class also.